# How to make Laguerre's equation into Sturm-Liouville form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

how do I put Laguerre's diff equation into Sturm-Liouville form?

$$xy'' + (1 - x)y' + λy = 0$$

I have to use the integrating factor method, for which I obtained $e^{-x}$

Is the integrating factor correct? How do I go about completing it? Many thanks.

Comment: , This is a routine problem of Frobinus series solutions around $x=0.$

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. We just multiply by $e^{-x}$:
$$
\underbrace{e^{-x}xy'' + e^{-x}(1 - x)y'}_{=\left(xe^{-x}y'\right)'} + λe^{-x}y = 0,
$$
and then we get
$$
\left(xe^{-x}y'\right)'+λe^{-x}y = 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you Wang, how would we apply this to Tchebycheff's and Hermite's differential equations? I can work out the integrating factor for those, but applying it and utilising the same method as above does not seem to work

Comment: See for example  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873421/how-to-reduce-this-to-sturm-liouville-form?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The general second order ODE 
$$f(x)y''(x)+g(x)y'(x)+h(x)y(x)=0\tag 1$$
is transformed to a Sturm-Liouville ODE 
$$\left(p(x)y'(x)\right)'+q(x)y(x)=0\tag 2$$
thanks to the change of functions :
$$\begin{cases}
p(x)=\exp\left(\int \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx \right) \\
q(x)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}\exp\left(\int \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx \right)
\end{cases} \tag 3$$
This is easy to prove from Eq.$(2):\quad py''+p'y'+qy=0$ compared to Eq.$(1)$ 
$$y''+\frac{p'}{p}y'+\frac{q}{p}y=y''+\frac{g}{f}y'+\frac{h}{f}y\quad\implies\quad\begin{cases}
\frac{p'}{p}=\frac{g}{f} \\
\frac{q}{p}=\frac{h}{f}
\end{cases}$$
In the case of $\quad xy''+(1-x)y'+\lambda y=0$
$$f(x)=x\quad\;\quad g(x)=1-x\quad\;\quad h(x)=\lambda$$
$$\begin{cases}
p(x)=\exp\left(\int \frac{1-x}{x}dx \right)=xe^{-x} \\
q(x)=\frac{h(x)}{f(x)}\exp\left(\int \frac{g(x)}{f(x)}dx \right)=\frac{\lambda}{x}xe^{-x}=\lambda e^{-x}
\end{cases}$$
$$\boxed{\left(xe^{-x}y' \right)'+\lambda e^{-x}y=0}$$
Of course, in the present very simple ODE, there is no need for the general calculus. Only inspection is sufficient to find the above result.

In case of Tchebycheff's and Hermite's differential equations use the equations $(3)$ to compute $p(x)$ and $q(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also transform to normal form by a substitution
$$
          y = e^{x/2}f.
$$
The equation for $f$ is$$
   x\left(e^{x/2}f''+e^{x/2}f'+\frac{1}{4}e^{x/2} f\right) \\+(1-x)\left(e^{x/2}f'+\frac{1}{2}e^{x/2}f\right)\\+\lambda e^{x/2}f = 0,
$$
or
$$
       xf''+f'+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x)f+\lambda f = 0 \\
        (xf')'+(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}x+\lambda)f = 0.
$$
This is not what you asked for, but it's an alternative way to approach the problem that leads to a simpler equation with polynomial coefficients in self-adjoint form.